# Manually Checking of Value Changes in Tables for SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

An example to the problem:
There are 3 columns present in my SQL database.

```
+-------------+------------------+-------------------+
| id(integer) | age(varchar(20)) | name(varchar(20)) |
+-------------+------------------+-------------------+
```

There are a 100 rows of different ids, ages and names. However, since many people update the database, age and name constantly change.

However, there are some boundaries to age and name:

- Age has to be an integer and has to be greater than 0.
- Name has to be alphabets and not numbers.

The problem is a script to check if the change of values is within the boundaries. For example, if age = -1 or Name = 1 , these values are out of the boundaries.

Right now, there is a script that does insert * into newtable where age < 0 and isnumeric(age) = 0 or isnumeric(name) = 0;

The compiled new table has rows of data that have values that are out of the boundary.

I was wondering if there is a more efficient method to do such checking in SQL. Also, i'm using `microsoft sql server`, so i was wondering if it is more efficient to use other languages such as `C#` or `python` to solve this issue.

Comment: Yes, you can apply constraints.

Comment: You shouldn't store age. People tend to become older, every year. Store date or year of birth instead.

Comment: Why do you store the age in VARCHAR field. TINYINT is enough. The range is from 1 to 255.

Comment: You need to have longer length for name. VARCHAR(20) wont be sufficient, I think.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply check constraint. Replace 'myTable' with your table name. 'AgeCheck' and 'NameCheck' are names of the constraints. And AGE is the name of your AGE column.

```
 ALTER TABLE myTable 
    ADD CONSTRAINT AgeCheck CHECK(AGE > 0 ) 

    ALTER TABLE myTable 
    ADD CONSTRAINT NameCheck  CHECK ([Name] NOT LIKE '%[^A-Z]%')
```

See more on [Create Check Constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-check-constraints?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: This is the correct solution.  Let the database validate data integrity.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to automatically insert the invalid data into a new table, you can create AFTER INSERT Trigger. I have given snippet for your reference. You can expand the same with additional logic for name check.

Generally, triggers are discouraged, as they make the transaction lengthier. If you want to avoid the trigger, you can have a sql agent job to do auditing on regular basis.

```
CREATE TRIGGER AfterINSERTTrigger on [Employee]
FOR INSERT 
AS
BEGIN 

    DECLARE @Age TINYINT, @Id INT, Name VARCHAR(20); 

    SELECT @Id = ins.Id FROM INSERTED ins;
    SELECT @Age = ins.Age FROM INSERTED ins;
    SELECT @Name = ins.Name FROM INSERTED ins;

    IF (@Age = 0)
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [EmployeeAudit]( 
           [ID]
          ,[Name]
          ,[Age])
    VALUES (@ID,
        @Name,
        @Age);
    END

END
GO
```